# Tax deduction for unclaimed commuter benefit

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, taxable-benefits

I paid for a few months of a commuter benefit I never used, then left that employer. According to [§1.132–9 in the CFR](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.132-9), these funds can't be returned by employers (see Q-14/A-14).

So I basically gave this money to my former employer, though I might have technically agreed to a salary reduction rather than allocating pre-tax money to the benefit.

Is there a tax deduction for losing funds this way? I assume it'd be similar to unused FSA funds at the end of the year.

Answer (score 4):

You already received a tax deduction, more or less, as you didn't pay tax on this income.

Beyond that, no; the money is lost if you don't spend it.  See [this explanation](http://finance.zacks.com/can-deduct-forfeited-fsa-10928.html) for example, among many others; it's specific to FSA, but they work generally the same way.

To go into a bit more detail, read [the IRS publication on the subject](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15b.pdf); basically, what's happening here is that you're receiving a fringe benefit, rather than salary.  So yes, you agreed to voluntarily reduce your salary by $255 or whatever per month in exchange for funds in this account.

As such, they're nontaxable, which both your employer and you find helpful; but the downside is it's not really your money - it's a fringe benefit.  Nice that it's tax free, and dissimilar to a medical or dependent care FSA, it doesn't have an expiration date; but it does go away when you leave your employer, and you don't get it back.  It's money you never had.